# Inject node module variable to scope

Tags: javascript, node.js, scope, node-modules

Is it possible to do achieve this behavior using node modules?

module.js:

```
module.exports = function () {
    var test.fn = function () {
        console.log("$test.fn()");
    }

    var test.fn2 = function () {
        console.log("$test.fn2()");
    }

    var variable = "test";
};
```

app.js:

```
require("./module.js")();

test.fn();
test.fn2();
otherFunction(variable);
```

I dont want to do anything like this `$ = require("./module.js")(); $.test.fn();`
I want to inject this variables into app.js scope without wrapper variable.

#### Edit:

I have ended up using this:

module.js:

```
module.exports = function () {
    eval(String(inject));

    var inject = (
        this.$module1 = {},
        this.$module1.fn = function () {
            console.log("$module1.fn()");
        }
        );
};
```

app.js:

```
require("./module.js")();

$module1.fn();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The top level scope in a module is actually a function scope (the node.js loader wraps each module in a function that it then calls to execute the code in the module).  Thus, there is no publicly available "root" object that we can programmatically assign properties to.

So, that means that it is not possible in a module to programmatically add new variables at the top level of the module scope without using `eval()` in a fairly big hack.  Function scopes just don't work that way in Javascript.

You could also have the module assign things to the `global` object where they can be used without a prefix, but this is NOT a recommended practice in any way.  The whole point of node.js modules is to avoid using any globals and to make code entirely self contained with little chance of global collisions.

Or, you could have your module export a giant string of Javascript and then `eval()` it inside of app.js in order to define new variables in the module scope.  Again - not recommended.

Your best best is do things the "node.js way" and put everything on an object and export that object.  Here's one variation:

app.js

```
var test = require("./module.js")();

test.fn();                  // "executing fn"
test.fn2();                 // "executing fn2"
console.log(test.myVar);    // "test"
```

module.js

```
module.exports = function () {
    return {
       fn: function () {
           console.log("executing fn");
       },
       fn2: function() {
            console.loog("executing fn2");
       },
       myVar: "test"
    }
};
```

Comment: And as i said this is exactly what i do not want to achieve. Is there any other way to inject variables to scope?

Comment: @ddl - I answered your question that you cannot do that unless you want to get into using `eval()` with strings in a fairly hackish way.  I explained a bit more about why you cannot do this with normal Javascript in my answer.

Comment: @ddl - if you want to do it with `eval()` then have your module export a giant string of Javascript and have your app.js get that string from the module and `eval()` it into app.js.  I won't advise doing that.  The module architecture in node.js leads to `moduleName.method()` as the most common design pattern and most node.js developers just get used to that.  If you really want a shortcut, you can assign module variables to your own local variables, but you can't do that in an automated way with `eval()`.

Comment: @ddl - it feels like you're just trying to avoid typing `moduleName.method()` for things in a module.  That is the "node.js way" and it is done that way for a number of legitimate reasons.  If you want to write robust, reusable node.js code that can be shared with others, I'd suggest you learn and use the common node.js design patterns, even if they feel a little bit different or awkward at first.  There's logic behind the way it works.

Comment: I know that I want to do a crazy thing but I have found a way of doing that, thanks for feedback `module.exports = function () {
 eval(String((
  this.$fn = function () {
   console.log("$test.fn()");
  }
  ));
};`

Answer (score 0):

**This answer should not encourage you to use `global` within your node.js modules (see jfriend00's comments above) as it makes your code vulnerable for name collisions with other modules and thus your modules less portable.**

Within module.js you have access to the `global` object of node.js runtime environment.

**module.js:**

```
global.test = {
    fn: function() {
        //Do something
    },
    fn2: function() {
        //Do something different
    },
    variable: "test variable"
}
```

**app.js**

```
require("./module.js"); //just include, no need for a wrapper variable
test.fn();
test.fn2();
console.log(test.variable);
```

Note that this technique will overwrite the global variable `test` if it already exists.

Comment: Frown.  Using globals in node.js, just to save a little typing is NOT a recommended practice.

Comment: Agree on that, I just wanted to to show this possibility as @ddl explicitly asked for a way to make module objects available in global scope.

Comment: Actually, the OP asked for "app.js scope", not global scope.  They are not the same.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like that using an IIFE.  The method, when required, will automatically run and return an object, which you can then use in your application.

**module.js:**

```
global.test = (function() {
  return {
    fn: function() {
      console.log("executing fn");
    },
    fn2: function() {
      console.log("executing fn2");
    },
    variable: "test"
  }
})();
```

**app.js**

```
require("./module.js"); //just include, no need for a wrapper variable
test.fn();
test.fn2();
console.log(test.variable);
```

Note that this technique will overwrite the global variable `test` if it already exists.